# Inner Workings of Unity3d's GUI.Button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm still pretty new to scripting in Unity3D, and I'm following along with a tutorial that uses GUI.Button() to draw a button on the screen.

I am intrigued by how this function works. Looking through the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html), the proper use of GUI.Button is to invoke the function in an if statement and put the code to be called when the button is pushed within the if statement's block.

What I want to know is, how does Unity3D "magically" delay the code in the if statement until after the button is clicked? If it was being passed in as a callback function or something, then I could understand what was going on. Perhaps Unity is using continuations under the hood to delay the execution of the code, but then I feel like it would cause code after the if statement to be executed multiple times. I just like to understand how my code is working, and this particular function continues to remain "magical" to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the right term, but I usually refer to such system as **immediate mode GUI**.

> how does Unity3D "magically" delay the code in the if statement until
>   after the button is clicked?

[GUI.Button](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html) simply returns true if a click event happened inside the button bounds during last frame. Basically calling that function you are **polling**: every frame for every button asking the engine if an event which regards that button (screen area) is happened.

> If it was being passed in as a callback function or something, then I
>   could understand what was going on

You are probably used to an `MVC` like pattern, where you pass a controller delegate that's called when an UI event is raised from the `view`. This is something really different.

> Perhaps Unity is using continuations under the hood to delay the
>   execution of the code, but then I feel like it would cause code after
>   the if statement to be executed multiple times.

No. The function simply returns immediately and return true only if an event happened. If returns false the code after the if won't be executed at all.

Side notes:

- That kind of system is hard to maintain, especially for complex structured GUI.
- It has really serious performance implications (memory allocation, 1 drawcall for UI element)

Unless you are writing an editor extension or custom inspector code, I'd stay away from it. If you want to build a menu implement your own system or use an external plugin (there are several good ones NGUI, EZGUI,..).
`Unity` has already announced a new [integrated UI System](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/28/overview-of-the-new-ui-system/), it should be released soon.

Comment: @heisenburg, 1 drawcall per gui element is no longer true, performance is quite good these days. Also, the GUI performs in several PHASES, so it can for instance, determine input to text fields, which button is on top etc.

Comment: I see now that I was mistaken in the overall role of the OnGUI function itself. If it gets called every frame, then it would be trivial for the GUI.Button code to perform a polling function. For some reason I had the concept of OnGUI being called once for initialization - probably because that's the way the GUI.Button function appears to work on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The unity3d gui goes through several event phases, or in the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event.html)

> Events correspond to user input (key presses, mouse actions), or are UnityGUI layout or rendering events.
>
> For each event OnGUI is called in the scripts; so OnGUI is potentially called multiple times per frame. Event.current corresponds to "current" event inside OnGUI call."

In OnGUI you can find out which event is currently happening with >Event.current

The following events are processed [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.html):

> Types of UnityGUI input and processing events.

```
-MouseDown
-MouseUp,mouse button was released
-MouseMove,Mouse was moved (editor views only)
-MouseDrag,Mouse was dragged
-KeyDown, A keyboard key was pressed
-KeyUp  A keyboard key was released.
-ScrollWheel    The scroll wheel was moved.
-Repaint    A repaint event. One is sent every frame.
-Layout A layout event.
-DragUpdated    Editor only: drag & drop operation updated.
-DragPerform    Editor only: drag & drop operation performed.
-DragExited Editor only: drag & drop operation exited.
-Ignore  Event should be ignored.
-Used   Already processed event.
-ValidateCommand    Validates a special command (e.g. copy & paste).
-ExecuteCommand Execute a special command (eg. copy & paste).
-ContextClick   User has right-clicked (or control-clicked on the mac).
```

Unity GUI has much improved lately and is quite usefull if you want to handle things programmatically. If you want to handle things visually, i recommend looking at the plugins heisenbug refers to.

If you decide to use unity gui, i recommend using only one object with ongui, and let this object handle all your gui.